# Evaluating `zipWith (+) [1,2] [3,4]` using equational reasoning

Tags: haskell, equation

[`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zipWith) definition

```hs
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith f = go
  where
    go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go xs ys
```

has a local definition bound to the name `go`.

If I proceed the evaluation of `zipWith (+) [1,2] [3,4]`

```
  zipWith (+) [1,2] [3,4]    -- 1
= go [1,2] [3,4]             -- 2
= (+) 1 3 : go [2] [4]       -- 3
= ...
```

line 3 is not correctly justified. `(+)` is available inside `go` scope, but `(+)` function can't appear "out of nowhere" in line 3 using equational reasoning. How can I proceed ?

Comment: Your third line seems to follow straightforwardly from your second line and the definition of `go`, at least to me. Can you elaborate more on what you think the problem is?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. `go` closes over `f`, so when you expand `go`, the value of `f` appears in that expansion.

Comment: Why not? The worst case is you're skipping a step. `f = (+)` is in scope. That's an equation. You're applying that substitution at the same time you're applying the `go` substitution, but I don't see anything wrong with doing that all as one step.

Comment: `= go [1,2] [3,4]`, where `go` is [… as defined …], where `f = (+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could reason would be like this:

```
zipWith (+) [1,2] [3,4]
= { definition of zipWith }
let go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = (+) x y : go xs ys
in go [1,2] [3,4]
= { definition of go, third case }
let go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = (+) x y : go xs ys
in (+) 1 3 : go [2] [4]
```

This way `+` doesn't appear "out of nowhere" -- it appears directly as the creation of a closure after the beta reduction of `zipWith` applied to `+`.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I can't thank you enough. I've updated my answer.

Comment: And thank you for the edit. I wondered about those steps, too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much everyone. I am able to see it. And that's why `go` isn't available outside `zipWith` definition. The `f` in `go`'s third equation would have an actual parameter when `zipWith (+) [1,2] [3,4]` is called. Thus,

```
go (1:[2]) (3:[4]) = (+) 1 3 : go [2] [4]
```

would hold.

EDIT:

Thanks to @Daniel Wagner, I was finally able to fully grasp it.
I can rewrite `zipWith` definition as:

```hs
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith f = 
    let go [] _ = []
        go _ [] = []
        go (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go xs ys
    in go
```

Then, I can reduce the expression in the following manner:

```hs
zipWith (+) [1,2] [2,4]
= { definition of zipWith }
let go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = (+) x y : go xs ys
in go [1,2] [2,4]
= { definition of go, third equation }
let go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = (+) x y : go xs ys
in (+) 1 3 : go [2] [4]
= { definition of go, third equation }
let go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = (+) x y : go xs ys
in (+) 1 3 : ((+) 2 4 : go [] [])
= { definition of go, first equation }
let go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = (+) x y : go xs ys
in (+) 1 3 : ((+) 2 4 : [])
= { definition of + and list-syntax sugar }
let go [] _ = []
    go _ [] = []
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) = (+) x y : go xs ys
in [4,6]
= { let reduction }
[4,6]
```